# .mswallet item 3rd party web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have implemented Apple Passbook in an asp.net web api and now i will implement microsoft wallet items, the concept seems to be the same, but i cannot find a description of the 3rd party web service for updating the mswallet item.
At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631256.aspx i can find:
"The phone fetches an updated .mswallet item from a 3rd party service. The item will be downloaded from the 3rd party service without prompting the user. This happens when the user opens Wallet or when they tap refresh. The system will try to download an update for each package that has a WebServiceUrl and AuthenticationToken defined."
Does anyone have a documentation about the webservice i have to implement for this scenario.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to allow the wallet to pull down the mswallet from a URL:

Whenever Wallet is opened by the user or the user taps refresh, the phone will attempt to update the contents of each card that has a WebServiceUrl and AuthenticationToken defined. This is done by making a GET request to the RESTful web service service identified by the WebServiceUrl of the Wallet item. The following is an example of a request the phone makes to get an update for an item.

https://WebServiceUrl/1/walletitems/id

Note: make sure that your context-type is:
'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms.wallet